# How to find the length of non-exclusive data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Looking to find the total length of non-exclusive data in DataFrame

df1:

```
        ID
0       7878aa
1       6565dd
2       9899ad
3       4158hf
4       4568fb
5       6877gh
```

df2:

```
        ID
0       4568fb  <-is in df1
1       9899ad  <-is in df1
2       6877gh  <-is in df1
3       9874ad  <-not in df1
4       8745ag  <-not in df1
```

desired output:

```
2
```

My code:

```
len(df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'] == False)
```

My code end up showing the total length of the DataFrame which is 6. How do I find the total length of non-exclusive rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin` with negation and then `sum`

```
(~df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])).sum()
```